# Accessing sql-db with EF in data-layer, how to pass data to service-layer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, separation-of-concerns

I need to access some data in an existing sql-database and publish it using a REST-Service (using Webapi).

In my previous, very small project I just accessed the EF-Context directly from my controllers, create some DTO's from my EF-Entities and return it to the caller. That was simple and I got it working really fast.

Now, the project is not much bigger but I want to do it 'the right way' this time as everyone is talking about a layering architecture, even for a small project, so unit-testing etc. is much easier.

Being a newbie on this (yes, I need to read more books) I decided to start reading tons of blog-posts about architectural design of an application and so on.

First thing was to get in touch with the various techniques on accessing the data in the database using EF (I'm using v6.2, DB-First). Some say, you need a repository for each entity, some say, create a generic repository and others say, repositories are the new evil, avoid them at all cost.

Some blog-posts I've read:

[generic-dal-using-entity-framework](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)

[is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-part-2/)

[repositories-on-top-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea](http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-on-top-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/)

[why-entity-framework-renders-the-repository-pattern-obsolete](http://cockneycoder.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/why-entity-framework-renders-the-repository-pattern-obsolete/)

[favor-query-objects-over-repositories](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/10/08/favor-query-objects-over-repositories/)

and so on.

Even some others say, that separating your EF-generated POCO's should be separated from the 'pure' EF-stuff like the EDMX: [splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects](http://nullablecode.com/2013/09/splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects/)

Some of the posts are old and may be obsolete but I'm just struggling on what is the best way to accomplish my task.

Right now, I have 4 Projects:

DGO.Core: Containing my DTO's

DGO.Data: Containing my EF-Stuff and 1 Repository-Class (see below for details).

DGO.Service: Referencing DGO.Data and accessing the methods exposed by the repository-class.

DGO.Webapi: Referencing all three DLL's but using the methods from the Service-Dll.
I need to reference the Data-Dll to be able to inject the data-repository.

So now my db-queries reside in the Data-DLL (in the so-called repository-class) which creates filled DTO's from my Core-DLL. These DTO's are then passed to the Service-DLL, which might process some logic here and there and then this DTO is passed to the Webapi-Controller.

Is this a common approach on passing these DTO's thru all layers?
Or is it better to split the POCO's from the EDMX and use these directly in my service-layer.

So the direction will be 'Data-Layer' -> 'POCOs' -> 'Service-Layer' -> 'DTOs' -> Client (Controller etc.).

And where should the queries take place? I think, in the Data-Layer but some say, it should be done in the service-layer. I think, the data-layer is responsible for querying the data and the service-layer is responsible for 'working' with the data.

Hope, I made my problems clear. Could provide code if it's necessary.
Thanks!

Comment: In your scenario, I think repository should return a domain entity and not the DTO. The mapping between the domain entity and DTO should happen in service. This way your Data Layer is unaware of anything else but the data which is represented using `EF-Stuff` and repositories. I think your approach might be taking you towards an Anemic Domain Model anti-pattern, read up on that.

Comment: @HubertJarema Thanks for your comment. Seems like this view on the ADM is outdated: https://blog.inf.ed.ac.uk/sapm/2014/02/04/the-anaemic-domain-model-is-no-anti-pattern-its-a-solid-design/
and
http://no-kill-switch.ghost.io/once-an-anti-pattern-anemic-domain-model/

Comment: Possibly, there are two schools of thinking here. From my experience, I've been using the ADM for a while (without knowing that it's called that) and I always had this problem that I would need to reuse some piece of logic from one service to another and I couldn't figure out what would be the best place to put it. After learning about Rich Domain Models and ADM I've started transitioning toward RDM more because of OOP and how easy it is to include Business Logic on the domain and then reuse it across services. I use mix of the ADM and the RDM now in my projects.

Comment: I'm still unsure which way to take. I've read a nice post here: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/3-ways-to-avoid-an-anemic-domain-model-in-ef-core
Paul talks about moving from ADM to a 'richer' DM by adding some behaviour to the dumb models. To me it looks like adding Business Logic to my models which should normally only take place inside my Service Layer? By using the RDM approach I have BL on different locations in my code which smells a bit bad in my opinion. I think this violates the SoC principle and makes it harder to test.
So would you make the EF-POCO's 'richer' as Paul suggests?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do. Why do you think that's a smell? The whole concept of Object Oriented Programming is keeping both data and logic in the same class so that you can encapsulate the data accessors. The way I do it, is let's say I have a User table, with User.cs EF Entity. I would have a `bool ValidateForAdding() `function that would check if all is good in the class before inserting. But the UserService would handle calling the repository to actually add the object. This isn't perfect and next step from this is DDD.

Comment: Also, how do you Validate now? In Service? How is that not a validation of SOLID? You service is a gigantic class doing all of the work. That's like going back in time to the 70s and doing procedural programming - calling functions one after one without any abstraction to it. You are just layering the responsibilities to services, repositories and so on, but if you think about it you are just calling a bunch on functions in different layers. I've been doing this for couple years now, and just recently started moving away from it so I know what you mean :)

Comment: Another point against ADM is, you have to keep your properties Public. So now, you can instantiate your `User` class any way you like and you can do with the data anything you want because you have access to all properties. You offload the work to your `Service` layer which leaks your object structure away. Why does Service layer need to worry about how to Validate the User? Shouldn't User know how to do that? Why are you allowing instantiating the User without the Username in your Service? You shouldn't! So you don't allow having an empty constructor and you have one with Username param.

Comment: Yeah, my Service-Class is big. My UI-Layer does a bit of input validation and the Service performs some 'deeper' checking and triggers the update.
Ok, I'll try the approach Paul talks about to make my models smarter and stateful and see how it goes. It forces me to think more in terms of 'Action'-Methods that I expose from my models rather than just setting the properties from outside. The preferred way would then be 'DAL' -> 'RDM-Models' -> 'Service-Layer' -> 'DTO' -> 'UI-/Presentation-Layer'.
That also means, that the RDM-Model itself is responsible for updating its entity!?

Comment: My service layer has `UserRepository`, which accesses the Db. It would instantiate `var user = new User("username")` then validate `if(user.IsValid()` and add `_userRepository.Add(user)`. All this happens in service. User class only has `IsValid()` function and is not aware of how data is actually saved.

Comment: Oops, haven't seen your last comment while writing my reply. But I get your point.
Sounds easy for single entities with no dependencies but what about an update on a user which also needs to update some parts, say i.e. a role in a depended table?? Do the RDM calls some public method on the 'Role-RDM'?

Comment: Well, you would have `Roles` property on the `Users` object and you can call `foreach(var role in Roles) role.Validate()`. Or something like that. You already have the relationship, so you just access `public` functions on the other RDM.

Comment: Ok, but these public functions are all to be called by/from the service-layer, not from another RDM, right?

Comment: You can call them in either service layer or RDM. They are public. So the `role.Validate()` can be called from `User.IsValid()` which is called from `UserService.AddUser(AddUserDto addUserDto)`

Comment: I think it's better to call them all from one place. How do another dev know that the role-validation is called by the user-RDM and he/she doesn't need to do it from the service-layer? So I think I would validate the role from my service-layer using `role.Validate()` and add it to my User-RDM by calling `user.AddRole(role)`.

Comment: If you are adding an invalid `role` in `AddRole()` don't you think it's the responsibility of the `AddRole()` to ensure the role you are adding is actually valid? In this case, what is  stopping other developers from calling the `AddRole()` with a bad `role`? If you included the logic to validate the role being added in AddRole() you will always get good result and you don't have to depend on the developer calling it from service.

Comment: Shouldn't the constructor of the `role` ensures the role is valid? So you can't create a bad `role` :)
But ok, will think about that too. Driving home now, thanks for your helpful comments so far. Might get back to you with a bunch of more questions.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the constructor should do it. I am not really an expert in this, as I am relatively new to not using ADM so you might not get the best or correct answer here.